# How do you access the contents of a previous mount after switching to a different the partition?

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, home

I installed an additional Linux installation into a separate partition set the /home directory into that partition as well and afterwards I modified `/etc/fstab` to point to the old partition.

How can I access the contents of the initial /home directory?

```
# initial configuration
UUID=001  /disks/disk1part1  ext2  auto,users,rw,exec,relatime           0    0   
UUID=002  /                  ext4  defaults,relatime,errors=remount-ro   0    1   
UUID=003  /disks/disk26      ext4  auto,users,rw,exec,relatime           0    0   
UUID=004  none               swap  sw                                    0    0   

# changed configuration
UUID=001  /disks/disk1part1  ext2  auto,users,rw,exec,relatime           0    0
UUID=002  /                  ext4  defaults,relatime,errors=remount-ro   0    1
UUID=003  /home              ext4  auto,users,rw,exec,relatime           0    0
UUID=004  none               swap  sw                                    0    0
```

The initial system had no /home in /etc/fstab because it was under the root, and the second configuration added changed /home to /disks/disks26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a `mount --bind / /mnt` you can access the `/home` directory of your root partition as `/mnt/home`, even if `/home` is already mounted over.

Comment: Does that affect other directories already mounted under /mnt? Can another name be used besides /mnt?

Comment: If you mount something over `/mnt`, that will shadow all its previous content. I used `/mnt` because that's what routinely used for temporary mounts. You can use any other existing directory.

Comment: What does the `--bind` signify? Is there a special command to unmount it?

Comment: A *bind* mount, see `man mount`. You can simply `umount` it as any other mount if it's not in use.

Comment: @vfclists http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount

Answer (score 1):

A mere two edit (and two reboot).

1. comment line with /home; like

   ```
   ## UUID=003  /home              ext4  auto,users,rw,exec,relatime           0    0
   ```
2. reboot, log

   ```
   cd /
   mv /home /home.old
   mkdir /home
   ```

   edit /etc/fstab, uncomment.

---

What happened ?

As you guess new  /home was mount over old /home, there is no way, save umounting to see old /home.

If you could umount /home, there is no need to reboot on above commands.

Comment: Isn't it possible to access via another means without changing the fstab and rebooting and renaming it? I am thinking along the lines of perhaps finding the inode and renaming it. Does changing the /home `/etc/fstab` make the /home inaccessible completely? It has to be there somewhere.