# df -k not showing correct mount point

Tags: shell

I am trying to find the mount point of a directory using `df -k`. It shows the mount point is the same directory.

I know it is not as I see a bunch of directories having the same allocation and the same free space.

I also see `umount` and `mount` commands are not working. Neither is `free`. Only `du` command works.

The problem is I need to free up some space but I want to know where I need to free the space up to have affect on my directory.

**df -k Output**:

```
/home>df -k

Filesystem    1024-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on

/homemast/home/sraja5  1692020552  19509380   99%  6852553     7% /home/sraja5
/homemast/home/mjain3  1692020552  19509380   99%  6852553     7% /home/mjain3
/homemast/home/spura1  1692020552  19509380   99%  6852553     7% /home/spura1
/homemast/home/rshah53  1692020552  19509380   99%  6852553     7% /home/rshah53
/homemast/home/dmurthi  1692020552  19509348   99%  6852553     7% /home/dmurthi
```

**Mount Output**:

```
mount /home/hhebburs
mount: /home/hhebburs is not a known file system
```

As you can see in my `df` output, all home directories have their own mount point. But you see the total space and used space to be the same for all of them. So this means they are mounted in a common place. I was trying to find where they are mounted.  Any directions?

Comment: Could you perhaps show us the results of both `df -k` and `mount`?

Comment: Please show the output of `df` and `mount`

Comment: /home>df -k
Filesystem    1024-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/homemast/home/sraja5  1692020552  19509380   99%  6852553     7% /home/sraja5
/homemast/home/mjain3  1692020552  19509380   99%  6852553     7% /home/mjain3
/homemast/home/spura1  1692020552  19509380   99%  6852553     7% /home/spura1
/homemast/home/rshah53  1692020552  19509380   99%  6852553     7% /home/rshah53
/homemast/home/dmurthi  1692020552  19509348   99%  6852553     7% /home/dmurthi

Comment: this is the DF -k output

Comment: mount: /home/hhebburs is not a known file system

Comment: @hemanth comments don't have great formatting, could you please edit your question to include the output of the `df` and `mount` commands?

Comment: @EricRenouf  Done

Comment: What is the output of running `mount` with no arguments?

Comment: From what it looks like there, several users have their home directories mounted from `/homemast/home`, but perhaps not all users do, like, say, `hhebburs` does not so it's just a directory under `/home` and not a specific mount point

Comment: Please add the output for `cat /etc/mnttab`. Note that depending on the OS, the file name may be different, so first run `ls -l /etc/m*`to ckeck for the right filename.

Comment: Did you include all the mounted filesystems in your `df -k` output, or did you edit some of them out? If you edited them out please provide the full results. Also, please provide the output of `cd ; pwd; echo "$HOME"` thank you.

Comment: This looks like the result of [bind mounts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount)

Comment: @Barmar: How do i see which is the actual mount point of Bind Mounts?

Comment: Look for the mount point of the directory it translates to. So for `/home/sraja5`, look at the mount point of `/homemast/home/sraja5`.

Comment: @Barmar - Any pointers on how to do that . New to this mount stuff

Comment: Use the `mount` command.

Comment: Or `df /homemast/home/sraja5`

Comment: /home/hhebburs/temp>df -k /homemast/home/sraja5
Cannot find file system /homemast/home/sraja5

Comment: @terdon Unfortunately it is not possible to write comments in a way that it is possible to give the information I put in the answer.

Comment: @schily yes, that would indeed be a useful feature. Unfortunately, there isn't one and all we have is answers. Those, however, have relatively strict rules. And yes, there is a way to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). The main U&L room is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).

Comment: What OS is this? It looks vaguely like a Solaris non-global zone. Perhaps these are loopback mounts?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df -a
```

`-a` for *all* includes dummy filesystems

Comment: df -a .
df: illegal option -- a
Usage: df [-P] | [-IMitv] [-gkm] [-s] [filesystem ...] [file ...]

Comment: Which distro are you using