# Resizing directories

Tags: ubuntu, resize2fs

I am not too familiar with how volume sizing works, but I have a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04, and I noticed the home directory is all used up. I have a 1TB drive on this machine, how can I allocate more space to /home?

```
$ df
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                    8186844       4   8186840   1% /dev
tmpfs                   1639632     572   1639060   1% /run
/dev/md1                4095616  378936   3716680  10% /
none                          4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                       5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                    8198144       4   8198140   1% /run/shm
none                     102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr    3997376  901812   2869468  24% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var    3997376  550088   3221192  15% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home   3997376 3771276         4 100% /home
```

Comment: FYI it's not a *directory* you need to resize—it's a partition and/or logical volume, as well as the filesystem it contains.  (Knowing keywords can help you in searching.)  Hope you get the help you need.

Comment: It appears you're using LVM. Could you check with `vgs` if you have free space in your volume group vg00? If so, this is very easy, and you don't need to worry about any shrinking stuff in Thomas Dickey's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a VPS, I assume you do not have physical access to the machine, so the usual approach to resizing an in-use filesystem will not work (that would be to use a rescue cdrom).

In your listing, the `/dev/mapper/vgxxx` mountpoints are the way LVM volumes are mounted.

Tutorials on LVM are fairly easy to find.  The problem if you have used all of your space is that shrinking the volume group for a live filesystem is said to be risky.

If you ***cannot*** empty out `/home` then one way to rescue your system would be like this:

- seeing that you have enough space one either `/usr` or `/var` to hold both filesystems,
- you could copy all of `/var` to a temporary directory in the `/usr` tree, and
- add a line in `/etc/fstab` to use a bind-mount to make that copy of `/var` mounted *as* `/var`.
- comment-out the line in `/etc/fstab` for the "old" `/var`, reboot
- You would lose "some" updates to `/var` (between copying and rebooting), but the reboot would get the system back to normal operation.
- after rebooting, you could resize the (now-inactive) volume group where you have `/var`, and
- add the space (physical volumes) to the group containing `/home`.

Still, making a backup first is always a good idea.

Further reading:

- [What is a bind mount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount)
- [How to Shrink an LVM Volume Safely](https://blog.shadypixel.com/how-to-shrink-an-lvm-volume-safely/)

Per comment, you actually have unused space on your disk, so in this instance it is not necessary to shrink one volume to make room for another.  I will leave the work-around suggested since it could be useful advice.

However - when simply *growing* a logical volume, you have to add space to the volume and then resize the filesystem (the part that you *care* about).  LVM is three layers (seen with `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay`).  If `pvdisplay` does not reflect your 1Tb, you will have to use `fdisk` to add a partition to the set of physical volumes.  Then update the volume group, adding the physical volume.  Finally use `resize2fs` to increase the size of the filesystem inside that volume group.  Here are some useful links:

- [Extending an LVM volume: Physical volumes (partitions) -> Volume groups -> Logical volume -> Filesystem](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/extending-lvm)
- [11.9. Extending a logical volume](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/extendlv.html) (LVM HOWTO)

Comment: If I unmount /home can I safely resize it then?

Comment: OP says he has 1TB, but total size of partitions is ~16GB. OP should have plenty of space left in the volume group, no need to shrink anything—just grow home.

Comment: ah - I have trouble counting digits...  Agree that OP should then be able to simply grow the home-volume.