# What occupies space in overlayfs

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage, overlayfs

I have a linux with a read only root filesystem and a read-write overlayfs mounted over it:

```
# mount
overlayfs on / type overlayfs (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/root_ro/,upperdir=/root_rw/)
...
```

The overlayfs is almost  full

```
# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlayfs              4003548   3995012      8536  99% /
...
```

How can I identify files consuming the read/write part of the overlayfs? The `du` does not differentiate space occupied on ro and rw media. I have found the option `-fstype type` in `find` but my linux has busybox and the find does not support this option there.

EDIT: add  output from `cat /proc/mounts`

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=1026976,nr_inodes=256744,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sda1 /root_rw ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
ubi0:rootfs /root_ro ubifs ro,noatime,nodiratime 0 0
overlayfs / overlayfs rw,relatime,lowerdir=/root_ro/,upperdir=/root_rw/ 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a notion of “what occupies the space” in an overlay filesystem. Each branch of the union has its own space occupation. Run `du` on both branches. If it's getting more full, the read-write branch is the culprit.

Since the overlay mount shadows its branches (`/root_ro` and `/root_rw` are hidden by the mount on `/`), you need to gain access to the branches. You can do that by mounting the block device again (Linux supports this, at least for most block device types):

```
mkdir /media/root_ro /media/root_rw
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/root_rw
mount ubi0:rootfs /mnt/root_ro
du /mnt/root_ro /mnt/root_rw
```

Comment: I do not see `/root_ro` and `/root_rw` in the filesystem. I am not an overlayfs expert but I guess /root_ro and /root_rw are available only during an early boot stage and then system does "a magic" and these directories are not visible anymore.

Comment: @ZabojCampula Oh, yeah, sorry, the filesystem is mounted on `/`. You can still access the branches through a [bind mount](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) in a different location. They might be mounted somewhere already. Check the output of `cat /proc/mounts` — if you don't understand how to find it, add this output to your question.

Comment: It is not mounted I think. Nevertheless I put the `/proc/mounts` to the question.

Comment: @ZabojCampula Hmm, right, so the mount on `/` shadows the mount points. There's a solution in your case (see my edit) but [I don't know if there's a general solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277883/accessing-a-shadowed-mount-point).

Answer (score 1):

Unmount the overlay filesystem, and then mount it somewhere else and check it using `du`.  If I understand them correctly, that should let you see what's in it.

Comment: +1 because looks a good idea and it should help. But not acceptable answer for me because I want to do that on running system - no umount possible.