# Accessing a shadowed mount point

Tags: linux, mount

A **mount point** `/mnt/sub` is shadowed by another mount point `/mnt`. Is it always possible to access the mounted filesystem?

Root access is a given. The system is a reasonably recent Linux.

Example scenario: [accessing the branches of an overlay root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277277/what-occupy-space-at-overlayfs)

The basic sequence of operations is:

```
mount device1 /mnt/sub
mount device2 /mnt
```

After this `/mnt/sub` is a file on `device2` (if it exists). The question is how to access files on `device1`.

Some devices can be mounted twice, so `mount device1 /elsewhere` would work. But this doesn't work for all devices, in particular not for FUSE filesystems.

This differs from the [already covered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/access-to-original-contents-of-mount-point) case where a *subdirectory* is shadowed by a mount point, but the mount point of the subdirectory is itself visible, and a bind mount can create an unobscured view. In the example above, `mount --bind / /elsewhere` lets us see the `/mnt/sub` directory from the root filesystem on `/elsewhere/mnt/sub`, but this question is about accessing the filesystem on `device1`.

Comment: A quick test shows the shadowed directory is accessible using `/proc/PID/cwd` for a process that was running in it before the shadowing mount. That won't do, I guess?

Comment: @muru That only works if the directory was the current directory of some process. It doesn't work in general for the scenario that inspired this question, which was accessing a branch of an overlay filesystem that was mounted on `/`.

Comment: Depending on how early it happened, wouldn't init's CWD still be in the old `/` in that scenario? It wouldn't work in general since there's no way to make sure a process is started in the old mount point, but with `/`, init is a good candidate, hopefully?

Comment: @muru Not if the branch is a separate filesystem rather than a part of the root filesystem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
# unshare --mount  # this opens a sub-shell
# cd /
# umount /mnt
```

do what thou wilt

```
# exit  # close the sub-shell
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably comes too late, but the way I normally do this is:

- mount the original device again on a different directory
- the new directory now only contains the original device's folders, and not any submounts.
- this does not depend on mount order, kernel namespace support, etc!
- does not require you to touch / move the *current mount* (which may be used by your services)

---

Here's how this would work for your root device, for example:

```
mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv /mnt
cd /mnt
# this folder only contains files from the root device
```

In your example:

```
# your actual (untouched) work dirs
mount device1 /mnt/sub
mount device2 /mnt

# access /mnt/sub contents in another dir by remounting it there
mount device1 /mnt/tmp
cd /mnt/tmp
# any operations here apply solely to device1
```

Answer (score 0):

The files living on `device1` under `/mnt/sub` are not accessible through that path at all. Remount the device elsewhere, or make sure that the two devices are mounted in the opposite order.