# copy_only_missing? - Copy from /A to /C only paths missing on /B and /C - concise way

Tags: rsync, backup, synchronization

I'd like to copy from */A* to */C* only paths missing on */B* and */C*. (Please assume those are paths, and can represent also remote locations e.g. mounted via `sshfs`)

I wonder... **Is there more concise way then writing a loop, iterating over filesystem and making check, file by file ?**

Example contents of tree directories */A*, */B*, */C* :

*/A*:

```
/A/1abc/qwe
/A/2abc/asd
/A/3abc/zxc
/A/4abc/rty
```

*/B*:

```
/A/2abc/asd
/A/3abc/zxc
```

*/C*:

```
/C/1abc/qwe
```

expected:
to copy from */A* to */C* only path `4abc/rty`:

```
/A/4abc/rty -> /C/4abc/rty
```

To illustrate practical examples of */A*, */B*, */C*, leading to such scenario:

- you make backup, copy from some */source* (*/A*) to some */destination* (*/B*) and some paths failed to be copied. So you want to have copy anyway of missing ones. So you find */another_destination* (*/C*) that can accept them, and you want to copy only missing ones. Here are example limitations why copy from */A* to */B* could fail: disc got full; limitation of filesystem of */B* (like filename lenght), while not present on */C* filesystem; etc.

Comment: `A`,`B` & `C` are on same machine or are they remotely resided ?

Comment: Please assume that all are mounted, but might be over sshfs (so remotely over not fastest connection).

Comment: your example is bit confusing, regardless of  your title. If you can edit more it would be nice for me or for others too.

Comment: Sure! Let me rewrite a bit once I am back at desktop :).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make a [union mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) of B and C with C as the write branch. Then the problem reduces to copying from A to B+C only files missing on B+C, which can be done with

```
rsync -a --ignore-existing /A /B+C
```

For the union mount, one possibility is [unionfs-fuse](https://github.com/rpodgorny/unionfs-fuse).

```
unionfs-fuse -o cow /C=RW:/B=RO /B+C
```

Or unionfs:

```
mount -t unionfs -o dirs=/C=rw:/B=ro unionfs /B+C
```

Comment: By curiosity : why unionfs-fuse instead of in-krenel unionfs ? I guess, it was just hany to write for you but both would do the job - or are there some edge cases where uninfs-fuse would be better for this kind of application ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki It has just handy for me to write, most union mount systems can handle this. For a discussion of union mount systems, see [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282393/union-mount-on-linux) — when somebody answers!

Comment: `Too many open files (24)` by `rsync`. I wonder if setting higher like `-o max_files=32000` option for `unionfs-fuse` is good strategy?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Still I get `rsync: chown "/.../xyz" failed: Too many open files (24)` at some point and rsync does not rsync everything, and `unionfs-fuse` directory is not possible to `ls` anymore. Maybe I should try with `unionfs` or `AuFS` instead. I couldn't find `rsync` flag that could help for that.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki Oh, I'd never encountered that problem with unionfs-fuse. Presuming that unionfs-fuse is the culprit (the open file limit is per-user), another union mount implementation might help, and an in-kernel one (overlayfs, aufs) would not run into this problem.