# Symlink fallback

Tags: symlink

Is there a way for symlinks to have fallback? If the destination is not found, another one should be used.

I want to use a config file for a program that is different whether a drive is mounted or not. So I would have symlink to a config on that particular drive and if not found, it would use an alternative one.

I guess I could use a wrapper script that would check if a drive is mounted, link to a desired config and then run the application, but a wrapper script feels weird.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way with standard symlinks. They always point to a single target path.

However, in your particular case, you could make use of how a drive shadows a mount: if you point the config file to /path/to/mount/config.cnf, then you have one that's on the parent filesystem (used when the mount isn't present) and one on the mounted filesystem (used when the mount is present).

But I wouldn't recommend that—for one thing, it's hard to open them both at once to e.g., compare them. I'd personally go for a wrapper script over that, many times over. There might also be program-specific ways, but you didn't name the program.

Comment: it's a qbittorrent. I usually download all my files on a external hdd, but if the disk is not mounted, all kinds of seeding errors pop out, files start redownloading and other mess. I weep every single time I accidentaly open qbittorrent without the drive mounted. So I'd have a alternative/fallback torrent/file location.

Comment: @JonnyRobbie yeah, I suspect you just need a wrapper script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [union mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) for this. Showing one file if present in a certain place and another file if the first choice wasn't present is the whole point of union mounts. Symlinks won't help, except if to show the file in a different place from where the mount is.

```
mkdir ~/overridden
unionfs-fuse "/media/external:$HOME/overridable" ~/overridden
```

`~/overridden` shows a merge of the directory trees under `~/overridable` and `/media/external`. When a file is present in both, the one from `/media/external` is shown.

See also [Union mount on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282393/union-mount-on-linux) (when someone answers it…).