# symbolic link where link receives updates and original does not

Tags: linux, files, symlink

Is it possible to have, assigning groups or ownership, something like

`ln -s original link`

where the `original` folder will be updated, all `link` folders will receive the new files, but any change to the files will not be in the `original`. The user will have write permission to the folder, but not to the files.

Comment: . You didn't say when you needs these to happen.

Comment: *The user will have write permission to the folder, but not to the files.*  Note that, in general, that means the user will be able to delete or rename the files, as file deletion and renaming merely requires write permission to the directory, not the file itself.  You need to look into how files in `/tmp` are protected from removal by other users...

Answer (score 1):

A symbolic link is just a redirection sign telling the directory traversal code “look there instead”. Once you get to the location of the files, it doesn't matter how you got there, it's the same files.

What you describe is exactly one of the common use cases for [union mounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount). See also [Union mount on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282393/union-mount-on-linux) although as I write it doesn't have the comprehensive answer that I'd hoped for. The basic principle of a union mount of `override` over `original` mounted at `link` is that `link/file` is `override/file` if it exists and `original/file` otherwise.

On Linux you can make a union mount with the [overlay filesystem](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem). Something like this (untested):

```
mkdir override work
chgrp users override; chmod g+rwxs override
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=link,upperdir=override,workdir=work link
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux and Solaris you can also use a "reflink" to the original file.  A "reflink" is a copy of a file where only the metadata is initially copied.  Any changes to the copy do not propagate back to the original file.  Likewise, any changes to the original file are not reflected in the copy.  Reflinks require the underlying filesystem to support copy-on-write semantics.

Reflinks are supported on Linux by the BTRFS and [XFS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkfs.xfs.8.html) filesystems ([XFS requires kernel version 4.8 or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS#History)).  Reflinks can be created on Linux using the [`cp --reflink...` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) or the [`ioctl( ..., FI_CLONE, ...)` or `ioctl( ..., FI_CLONERANGE, ...)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ficlonerange.2.html) functions.

Solaris 11.4 supports reflinks on ZFS, where reflinks can be created with the [`cp -z ...` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/cp-1.html#scrolltoc) or [the `reflink()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37843/reflink-3c.html).