# Does remounting after changes to overlayfs underlying filesystem (UB) necessarily restore consistency?

Tags: linux, mount, overlayfs, union-mount

The [overlayfs documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html) states that "if the underlying filesystem is changed, the behavior of the overlay is undefined, though it will not result in a crash or deadlock."

And, indeed, I've observed that when I make changes to the lowerdir in an overlay mount, strange stuff happens. However, if I remount afterwards, the problems seem to be fixed.

If I ignore the documentation's advice and modify the underlying filesystem online, will `mount -oremount merged` *necessarily* fix any issues caused by doing so?

(Yes, yes, I know the documentation says "changes to the underlying filesystems while part of a mounted overlay filesystem are **not allowed**" (emphasis mine), but I've heard [otherwise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386758/173715).)

Comment: Just a word of caution with regard to "undefined behaviour": even if you find the actual behaviour works for you, this is still dangerous.  Undefined behaviour can change between minor versions of a module with zero warning.  Even without a code change it can work 999 times and fail catastrophically on the thousandth.

Comment: Yes, this is why I asked. If it weren't for having heard remounting will fix any inconsistencies, I would have just listened to the documentation.