# How do I mount a directory early as possible, at or just after fstab?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, directory, home

I want to keep the /home directory in a folder on a disk partition other than the boot partition.  Please note I said *folder*, not partition, meaning that **I do not want to mount an entire partition** as /home.

Bad fstab entry: `LABEL=G_Giant_257/common/home /home` would be exactly what I want, if only such syntax would work.

Actual (good) fstab:

```
LABEL=G_Giant_257 /mnt/g auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,nobootwait,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Now I need to get the command

```
mount /mnt/g/common/home /home
```

to execute before anything tries to access /home.  Of course, I want all references to any user's "/home/~" directory to access a sub-folder of /common/home on my G_Giant_257 partition.

**The kicker:** my root partition is ext4, the G_Giant_257 partition is NTFS, so I don't see how a link could be made to work.  I am running ubuntu 16.04.

What do you recommend, please?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prominently say this, as it's not directly related to the question.  But the more I work with NTFS shared between Windows and Unix, the more problems I find on the Unix side.  Most revolve around "unsettable" permissions (e.g. program requires this file not be world readable) or ownership demands of the Unix software.  Wine is particularly bad; one would think that a windows scaffolding emulator would be prepared to deal with windows file systems.  My initial optimism after sharing Mozilla and Thunderbird profiles (with links) has shattered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mount --bind` your `/home` in `/etc/fstab` with

```
/mnt/g/common/home /home none bind 0 0
```

(See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/613179/how-do-i-do-mount-bind-in-etc-fstab) on ServerFault.)

I have no idea how practical is to have `/home` on an NTFS filesystem.

Comment: I think [What is a bind mount?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) would be more helpful background that this SF question.

Comment: I'm in a mixed Windows Linux Mingw Cygwin environment, and it's easier to access NTFS from Linux than ext4 from Windows.  I check my mail, and run the browser from both Windows and Ubuntu, plus lots of development files live in /home/~.  I'm also more familiar with adjusting things likethe  mail store location on windows than on Linux.  So far, I've had good success sharing these things on NTFS.

Comment: @AlexP sorry, forgot to tag you on the previous comment.

Comment: @AlexP My conclusion is that /home on an NTFS is most impracticable (nay, impossible) with xfCE, Mate, Zorion, and I suspect, Gnome and Cinnamon. Too much use of permissions trying to protect the user from "inadvertently" changing things the desktop keeps in /home/.local or /home/.config, etc., coupled with hard failures when permissions aren't right.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't mount a directory; that is with block-device-based (normal) filesystems such as ext4.

What you can do instead is keep your *good fstab*:

```
LABEL=G_Giant_257 /mnt/g auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,nobootwait,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

And then remove `/home` and replace it with a symbolic link which points to the home folder on your NTFS partition:

```
ln -s /mnt/g/common/home /home
```

You may need to mess with the fstab entry a bit to get the permissions working, but unlike hardlinks, symbolic links can cross filesystems. During the time /mnt/g is unavailable, the link is considered *broken*, but the moment it gets mounted the link will resolve.

As for mounting home, fstab is the way to go. Nothing should be trying to access `/home` *too early*.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but not knowing the details of Ubuntu start-up and upstart/systemd etc., I feel more comfortable with the bind mount.  Besides, I've used that strategy with MinGW before.  Wish I could up-vote both answers.

Comment: @Rosa Hey, I can up-vote more than one answer!