# Link 2 existing files

Tags: mount, solaris, symlink, hard-link, bind-mount

I have 2 existing files : `abcd` and `xyz`.

```
$ cat abcd
abcd 
$ cat xyz
xyz
```

Now, when I try to softlink these files, I get this message :

```
ln: cannot create xyz: File exists
```

I do not want to use

```
ln -sf abcd xyz
```

command as it will overwrite the content of `xyz` with that of `abcd`.

What I want is: both `abcd` and `xyz` should display their original content once they are unlinked.

Or in other words, I just want to temporarily link both of these files.

Please suggest if there is any other solution to this other than soft/hard link like using mount, etc.

Edit : I am using `Solaris OS` which has no manual entry for commands like `mount --bind`,`mount -B`, `bindfs`, `fusermount`,etc

Also, I tried to use : `mount -o bind abcd xyz` and it gave following msg : `cannot open /etc/vfstab`. I checked and found out that `/etc/vfstab` was having only `Root` access.

Comment: `mv xyz xyz.orig`

Answer (score 17):

This is not what `ln` is meant to do.  `ln` creates a hardlink of an existing file, i.e., two (or more) directory entries that point to the same file in the disk.  Linked files work in a way that editing one will affect all.

The functionality you want is not something native to Unix (link files so that they appear as one and so that they can be unlinked later).  **Linux**, though, has (some years ago) implemented something called bind mounting, allowing a file or a directory to be mounted on top of another (files on top of files and directories on top of directories).

*Proposed solution:* If you want a file to appear "to be" another temporarily, then use bind mount (`mount -B file1 file2`).  This will mount `file1` on top of `file2`.  After unmounting this later, both files will show again as they originally exist.

```
# echo A >A

# echo B >B

# mount -B A B

# cat A
A

# cat B
A

# umount B

# cat A
A

# cat B
B
```

If you expected that the "linked" files show as a concatenation of both, you will have to create a third file and remove it later.

Comment: I didn't know this one. Why does it demand sudo priviliges?

Comment: If this allowed regular users to "fake" other users files contents this could create major security issues.  (I'm inclined to agree that if the user owns all involved files and directories this should be allowed.  Unfortunately it isn't).

Comment: Allowing regular users to do this could create a denial-of-service vulnerability through a flood of bind mounts. I don't know how well a typical Linux kernel handles millions of mount points. If somebody has a VM snapshot handy I'd be curious to find out. :-)

Comment: @DavidFoster - Yes, this makes sense.  Thank you for the input.   Anyway, the feature worth it, so there could be a limit/mount-quota/something-similar.  (a little off-topic just wondering philosophically...)

Comment: Bind mounting with `mount --bind` has existed in Linux for over a decade. This probably won't help the asker since the question was tagged Solaris. Also, it requires root. A similar solution is to use bindfs, which works on most unices and doesn't require root (provided that FUSE is allowed).

Answer (score 6):

This command:

```
ln -sf abcd xyz
```

does not overwrite the content of `xyz` with that of `abcd`, as you think. A symbolic link is not a file, so it doesn't contain any content.

If you want to temporarily link `xyz` to `abcd` while not loosing it's content, you need to store the content somehow.

- You can copy the contents to a temporary file. I guess no illustration for this is needed.
- You can also use the memory, that is store the contents in a variable.
- You can use a hard link.

Now I'll demonstrate the last one. You have `abcd` and `xyz`, as explained in your question.

1. Hard-link `xyz` with `zyx`, so that the contents is kept in `zyx` letting you manipulate `xyz`.

   ```
   $ ln xyz zyx
   ```

   At this point `xyz` and `zyx` are two hard links of the [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) containing the data `xyz`, as described in your question. You can check this with:

   ```
   $ cat zyx
   xyz
   ```
2. Now that `zyx` is in place, you can force the relinking of `xyz` to `abcd`.

   ```
   $ ln -sf abcd xyz
   ```

   `zyx` still keeps the characters `xyz`. You can check this with:

   ```
   $ cat zyx
   xyz
   ```

   While `xyz` is now soft-linked to `abcd`. To check run this:

   ```
   $ cat xyz
   abcd
   ```
3. Once you want to restore the starting state, relink `xyz` to the original contents. That is, relink it to the original inode.

   ```
   $ ln -f zyx xyz
   ```

   To check if it works:

   ```
   $ cat xyz
   xyz
   ```

   And now you can unlink the additional hard-link `zyx` with:

   ```
   $ rm zyx
   ```

   Or keep it for future operations. Either way `xyz` still contains what it did at the beginning.

   ```
   $ rm zyx
   $ cat xyz
   xyz
   ```

Comment: @VivekSingh Good. Accept the answer if it's satisfactory. And upvote it if you like me.

Comment: @VivekSingh - this is not necessary to store the contents temporarily as proposed above.  The expected behavior can be obtained using bind mount (if you are using Linux).  Please check my answer.

Comment: @Marcelo, I am using Putty console in a Windows 7 configuration system.  Unfortunately, I am getting this error, when I am using "mount --bind abcd xyz" or "mount -B abcd xyz"  :                                         mount -B abcd xyz
mount: illegal option -- B.  Can you please elaborate or provide exact command for the same.

Comment: @VivekSingh - Some questions: Is the target system a Linux? ; Are you entering the command as root?  (please post the output of `uname -a` and `whoami`)

Comment: @Marcelo Yes, I am using a Windows machine to access Solaris OS(target system) using Putty console. I guess that answers your question. Also, I am not the root user.

Comment: Ok, so this is what it seems to be the issue.  I'm not sure Solaris supports bind mounting.  AFAIK, this is a Linux feature.

Comment: @VivekSingh You may need to use the long option name, ie `--bind`. See `man mount` on the OS you work on, ie on Solaris.

Comment: @Marcelo ,Yes, I had gone through manual page of mount, but it was not having any option of "bind". Please let me know if there is any other way except using softlink.

Comment: @VivekSingh - In case Solaris doesn't support bind mounting nativelly, please research about bindfs (part of FUSE, which I'm almost sure Solaris does support).

Comment: @VivekSingh See this for more details about bind mounting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount

Comment: @tomas Thanks but I guess none of these options, mount --bind, bindfs,mount_nullfs are working on my OS. I got this o/p on running following command :  $ mount -o bind abcd xyz
mount: Cannot open /etc/vfstab

Comment: @VivekSingh So it may be the lack of priviliges, right?

Comment: @tomas, Yes /etc/vfstab has root access only.

Comment: @VivekSingh - I guess that since you don't own root privileges you'll have to work with scripts using `cp`, `ln`, etc, to backup the original contents, linking the files and then restoring them back.  `mount` is a command supposed to be run as root.  You could talk to your system administrator so that he could allow you to use a very specific mount line and parameters with `sudo`, but I guess this may be more difficult to convince than practical (Still, I'm not even sure Solaris supports bind mounting, so it may worth nothing in the end).

Comment: @Marcelo, Yes, that's the problem but anyways thanks a lot to both of you guys, cleared many of my doubts!!!

Comment: Rather than writing up scripts to do this manually, if the files and directory aren't too big, you might be able to create agit folder. Create a branch, make the changes, commit. When you're done, just switch to the previous branch. You can switch back and forth between branches to switch between the two setups.

Comment: @tomas Could you please help me with another question of mine : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372009/mailx-replace-from-address-with-name?noredirect=1#comment662356_372009

Comment: @Raid_Master I don't know `mailx`, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, as an alternative to bind mount, you can also use overlay mount to link one file with another temporarily. The advantage of an overlay is that you can change overlay without needing root privilege, unlike bind mount which will require root privilege to shadow and unshadow files.

### Demonstration:

Create a test partition with some test files (note that you need root to create a mountpoint that isn't listed in /etc/fstab, but you won't need root for any of the other steps):

```
$ mkdir one two work mpnt
$ sudo mount -t overlay none -olowerdir=one,upperdir=two,workdir=work mpnt
$ echo "hello world" > one/abcd
$ echo "another" > one/xyz
```

We created the test files in folder `one` above, these files are also visible in the mount point `mpnt`.

```
$ ls -lh mpnt
total 8.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 lieryan lieryan 12 Jun 11 03:33 abcd
-rw-r--r-- 1 lieryan lieryan  8 Jun 11 03:33 xyz
```

Let's modify the files in mpnt:

```
$ ln -sf abcd mpnt/xyz
```

We modified mpnt/xyz above to be a symlink, but overlayfs redirects all writes to mpnt to the upperdir, so the symlink we created are actually written to `two`, we can see the symlink in folder `two` as well as `mpnt`:

```
$ ls -lh two
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lieryan lieryan 4 Jun 11 03:34 xyz -> abcd
$ ls -lh mpnt
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 lieryan lieryan 12 Jun 11 03:33 abcd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lieryan lieryan  4 Jun 11 03:34 xyz -> abcd
```

The symlink works as expected when used from `mpnt`:

```
$ cat mpnt/xyz
hello world
```

If we delete something from mpnt, overlayfs will also redirect the write to upperdir:

```
$ rm mpnt/xyz
```

In this case though, overlayfs actually creates a special character device file (notice the c attribute), called a whiteout file. When overlayfs sees this type of file in the upperdir, overlayfs pretends that the file don't exist in `mpnt`:

```
$ ls -lh mpnt 
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 lieryan lieryan 12 Jun 11 03:33 abcd
$ ls -lh two
total 4.0K
c--------- 1 lieryan lieryan 12 Jun 11 03:33 xyz
```

We can remove the special character file from the upperdir to restore xyz from lowerdir:

```
$ rm two/xyz  # delete the "whiteout" file
rm: remove write-protected character special file 'two/xyz'? y
```

Now `xyz` is visible again in mpnt, and has the same file content as one/xyz.

```
$ ls -lh mpnt 
total 8.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 lieryan lieryan 12 Jun 11 03:33 abcd
-rw-r--r-- 1 lieryan lieryan  8 Jun 11 03:33 xyz
$ cat mpnt/xyz
another
```

Comment: Why am I getting this: `overlayfs: filesystem on 'two' not supported as upperdir`?

Comment: @tomas: From `man mount`: `The upper filesystem will normally be writable and if it is it must support the creation of trusted.* extended attributes, and must provide a valid d_type in readdir responses, so NFS is not suitable`. What filesystem are you using as the upperdir?

Comment: This is new to me. My only disk is all ext4. If this is a good answer...

Comment: @tomas: what directory are you using for your test? If you are doing it on /tmp, that is mounted as tmpfs on some systems. tmpfs doesn't support extended attributes either, so it can't be used as upperdir. Check your mount table by running `mount` command.

Comment: type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=1c2cadf7870dc437,ecryptfs_sig=89832faac44a6443,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)

Comment: @tomas: you might want to try creating the upper directories outside of ecryptfs. I think currently ecryptfs can't be used for overlayfs' upper directory for some reason.

Comment: On the unencrypted it's ok. But I don't know what's going on in your command. Could you comment them, please?

Comment: @tomas: I've added some comments to the demonstration. HTH.

Comment: If this doesn't require root privileges as stated, why do you use `sudo` in the mount command in your answer? `sudo mount -t overlay ...`

Comment: @Marcelo: as I've stated above, this does not require root privilege to change the overlay files, the initial setup (i.e. setting up the mount in fstab), does still require root. Once you've got the mount setup in fstab, set up as user-mount, regular user can mount/unmount the overlay without requiring root.

Comment: Thanks. What is the mysterious `work` directory for?

Answer (score 2):

> both abcd and xyz should display their original content once they are unlinked

Then what you want is not a link. If two files are linked, then they have the same content. More precisely, two directory entries are linked if they point to the same file. Unlinking a file doesn't leave two files: unlinking a directory entry means removing this directory entry (the system call to remove a file is even called `unlink`).

There's no general feature to shadow a file with another file. You can use the [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/) filesystem to shadow a directory with another directory. To shadow the directory `xyz` with the directory `abcd`, run

```
bindfs -n -o nonempty xyz abcd
```

After this, the former contents of `abcd` are hidden, and accessing `abcd` in any way accesses `xyz`. Bindfs is a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem that creates a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount). To undo the shadowing and see the original content of `abcd`, unmount the filesystem:

```
fusermount -u abcd
```

Note that mounting a filesystem doesn't change what's stored on the disk. The shadowing is limited to your machine, and only lasts at most until the next reboot. If you want the shadowing to last, you need to add this mounting to the list of things to mount at boot time (`/etc/fstab`). But if you want the shadowing to last, then mounting is probably not the right approach: instead just move the file and create a symbolic link

```
mv abcd abcd.orig
ln -s xyz abcd
```

and to go back, remove the symlink and move back the original file

```
rm abcd
mv abcd.orig abcd
```

Comment: @Giles I have edited my question, can you please have a look again

Comment: @VivekSingh Re-read my answer. I didn't say to use `mount --bind`, in fact I told you it wouldn't work on Solaris. Use `bindfs` instead. It isn't part of the default installation, install it either from the site (click the link in my answer) or as a package if it's available as a package.

Comment: @Giles Thanks, in my case I have to `overshadow` one file with another which I guess is not possible, so I believe I have to use link approach only

Comment: @VivekSingh I suspect that making and removing a link is not the best approach, but it's difficult to say because you're [asking about your proposed solution rather than asking about your problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suggest asking a new question where you describe *your problem* and ask how to solve it, without insisting on a particular method.

Comment: @Giles Could you please help me with another question of mine : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372009/mailx-replace-from-address-with-name?noredirect=1#comment662356_372009

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand you, you want to link two files but you don't want to loose the data in both files.  You tagged your post with Solaris so i assume you use this operating system.  So refering to functionalities of other operating systems doesn't seem to be useful. This answer assumes that you are using one or more zfs datasets for the data.

You could simply make a zfs snapshot of your filesystem where you want to place the link instead of the file, make the ln -sf abcd xyz, do whatever you want with it and then roll back

```
root@solaris:/rpool# zfs create rpool/filesystem1
root@solaris:/rpool# mkfile 1k /rpool/filesystem1/file1
root@solaris:/rpool# mkfile 1k /rpool/filesystem1/file2
root@solaris:/rpool# ls -l /rpool/filesystem1
total 2
-rw-------   1 root     root        1024 Jun  8 20:33 file1 .  
-rw-------   1 root     root        1024 Jun  8 20:33 file2
root@solaris:/rpool# zfs snapshot rpool/filesystem1@withtwofiles
root@solaris:/rpool# rm /rpool/filesystem1/file2
root@solaris:/rpool# ln -s /rpool/filesystem1/file1 /rpool/filesystem1/file1
root@solaris:/rpool# ls -l /rpool/filesystem1
total 4
-rw-------   1 root     root        1024 Jun  8 20:33 file1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          24 Jun  8 20:33 file2 -> /rpool/filesystem1/file1
root@solaris:/rpool# zfs rollback rpool/filesystem1@withtwofiles
root@solaris:/rpool# ls -l /rpool/filesystem1
total 6
-rw-------   1 root     root        1024 Jun  8 20:33 file1
-rw-------   1 root     root        1024 Jun  8 20:33 file2
root@solaris:/rpool#
```

Instead of unlinking you just rollback the filesystem with the link