# Mailx replace from: address with name

Tags: solaris, mailx

How to replace sender address with his name using mailx command?

I was using following command but it was still giving mail address and not name :

`echo test | mailx -r "Singh,Vivek <vivek.x.singh@xyz.com>" -s "Test mail" vivek.x.singh@xyz.com`

I am currently using Solaris 10 OS.

What I want : In my mailbox, `from:` should show `"Singh,Vivek"` instead of `"vivek.x.singh@xyz.com"`

Comment: It's odd, but on a Solaris 10 server I have access to, removing the `-r` option seems to do what I think you desire.

Comment: That's not a valid address. A real name which contains a comma needs to be quoted. Try `mailx -r '"Singh, Vivek" <vivek.x.singh@xyz.com>'` to pass in an address in valid format.

Comment: @tripleee, It is still sending mail address and not name. Please test it at your end and let me know. I want `Singh, Vivek` in the sender address of my mailbox.

Comment: I don't have access to Solaris so I can't test.  Are you saying the From: header is not used to display the sender's identity in `mailx` on Solaris?

Comment: @tripleee See `mailx -r` is working fine but `-r` option is only accepting mail address as an argument. I was asking you if there is any way I can pass sender's name as an argument