# Swap 2 words without using 3rd word

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file named `swap`:

```
$ cat swap
aardvark BILL CLINTON dog
eternal CLINTON BILL forever
BILL good housekeeping BILL
```

I want to change all occurrences of `BILL` to `CLINTON`
and concurrently change all occurrences of `CLINTON` to `BILL`,
resulting in output as:

```
aardvark CLINTON BILL dog
eternal BILL CLINTON forever
CLINTON good housekeeping CLINTON
```

I know the classic solution:

```
sed -e 's/BILL/temp/g' -e 's/CLINTON/BILL/g' -e 's/temp/CLINTON/g'
```

but somebody challenged me, as an exercise, to do it without using a third word.

I was using following command, but it was working only on the first line:

```
$ sed 's/\(BILL\) \(CLINTON\)/\2 \1/g' swap
aardvark CLINTON BILL dog
eternal CLINTON BILL forever
BILL good housekeeping BILL
```

Note: I am using Solaris 10 OS.

How could I get the desired output while observing this artificial constraint?

Behavior for

```
MORBILLIFORM OVERBILLED
TOM, BILL, AND HARRISON
```

is unspecified.

Comment: By what logic is "bill bill" transforming to "clinton clinton" on the last line?

Comment: `sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/' swap`

Comment: Why such an artificial constraint?

Comment: @roaima Someone had thrown me a challenge to do this without using 3rd variable

Comment: @RakeshSharma, I guess swap is not the correct word for this scenario but I believe you understood what I want, let me know if you could help me with the whole scenario.

Comment: @Scott Thanks Man for editing the question!!

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe 's/(BILL)|CLINTON/$1 ? "CLINTON" : "BILL"/eg' swap
```

---

## Explanation:

`-p` option makes `Perl` read the file a la `awk`, line-by-line AND current record is auto-printed after all transformations have been applied.

The `s///` command works on the current line. The `/eg` pattern modifiers
are: `/g` will apply the transformation globally on the current line and not
just limit itself to the first had you not mentioned the `/g`. The `/e` is
the `eval`-uate modifier, which makes the `RHS` of the `s///` to be taken as
a `Perl` code and after it's evaluation what value it results in is taken as
as the RHS.

So, s/(BILL)|CLINTON/.../ will look for BILL or CLINTON in the current record
starting the scanning from the left. When BILL is found, then $1 is set and hence the Perl expression $1 ? "CLINTON" : "BILL" will evaluate to CLINTON which is what BILL is replaced with in the current record. But we"re done yet,
due to the `/g` modifier. Similarly, if CLINTON is found, then $1 is empty and
so the Perl expression $1 ? "CLINTON" : "BILL" is evaluated to BILL and which
is what CLINTON is replaced with in the record. This goes on till the end of
current reached , at which point it is printed to STDOUT due to the `-p` option.

```
sed -e 's/BILL\|CLINTON/\n&/g;s/\nBILL/CLINTON/g;s/\nCLINTON/BILL/g' swap
```

Comment: Thanks!! Perl command is working fine. Could you please explain what does "e" do in "eg"

Comment: In fact, Could you please explain whole perl command you have used here.

Comment: Thanks!! 1 more question, you have placed BILL in brackets "(BILL)" but CLINTON without brackets in s/(BILL)|CLINTON/,reason?

Comment: @Raid_Master Since there are only 2 possibilities, viz., we either match BILL or CLINTON, so that means if we don't match BILL => we have CLINTON.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i=="BILL") $i="CLINTON"; else if($i=="CLINTON") $i="BILL" } }1'  swap
```

The output:

```
CLINTON BILL
BILL CLINTON
CLINTON CLINTON
```

---

- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through all fields (*awk* treats whitespace(s) as default field separator)
- `if($i=="BILL") $i="CLINTON"` - if a field value is equal to `BILL` - assign it with `CLINTON`
- `else if($i=="CLINTON") $i="BILL"` - else if a field value is equal to `CLINTON` - assign it with `BILL`

Comment: awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i=="BILL") $i="CLINTON"; else if($i=="CLINTON") $i="BILL" } }1'  swap       
                                                                                                           awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @Raid_Master, that would not happen, except you are using non-Linux OS or different awk implementation. See this http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/need-solution-for-awk-syntax-error-near-line-1-error-4175431628/

Comment: I am using Solaris 10 OS

Comment: check your awk implementation

Comment: Could you please explain what this part your command is doing  : for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)(you are initializing i as 1 and equating it with "BILL"?? )

Comment: @Raid_Master This solution does the job you need, as you described it in your question. The for part iterates from first up to last field. Last field in awk is called NF.  This solution works because awk can split each line into fields (space separated) and can operate in each field one by one.

Comment: @Raid_Master, see my explanation

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, Just one more question, might be a silly one : At the end of your command you have used "} }1'", what is this "1" used for?

Comment: @Raid_Master A single 1 in awk instructs awk to perform it's default action = print the line. The awk is always following the pattern `condition{action}`. When you see awk code starting with `{....}` , condition is missing and is assumed as 1=true=the following action will always be performed. When you see thing like `1` or for an example something like `NF==2` without an explicit action given , without `{...}` following, the default action is performed = print the line. So the `1` here is used because previous `{action}` modified the fields of the line but they did not print the line.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou and Roman, following awk implementation worked for me on `Solaris 10` OS : `awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i=="BILL") $i="CLINTON"; else if($i=="CLINTON") $i="BILL" } print}' swap`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest and George, Thanks a lot man for clearing many of my doubts. I have one more request : could you please help me with  mailx command : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372009/mailx-replace-from-address-with-name?noredirect=1#comment662356_372009

Answer (score 1):

Another awk solution

```
awk '{
        while (match($0, /BILL|CLINTON/)) {
            printf "%s", substr($0, 1, RSTART-1);
            $0 = substr($0, RSTART);
            printf "%s", /^BILL/ ? "CLINTON" : "BILL";
            $0 = substr($0, 1+RLENGTH)
        }
        print
    }' swap
```