# What exactly happens behind a bind mount? (Linux 4.x)

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, bind-mount

From the answer to [What is a bind mount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590),

> It is possible to unmount /some/where, in which case /else/where remains mounted.

I checked the output of `mount` after performing a bind mount. The relevant lines are:

```
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/bind type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

According to Gilles's comments, a bind mount does not only bind the directories, but *the kernel additionally remembers "`/dev/foo` is mounted on `/else/where`"*. This agrees with what I saw in the mount info above.

Also, a bind mount is neither exactly "bind the directory" nor exactly "mount the underlying device again", since bind mounting mounts the device, but not the root structure of the device.

I think a bind mount actually "mounts an inode inside a device to a file" (note: directory is a special file), can anyone tell me if I made it right?

Comment: please copy important bits into the question: Make it self-contained.