# Find out which process has data open on the hard drive that is no longer visible in the directory tree

Tags: process, disk-usage, inode, open-files

On my server, the root partition is 73GB, but the disk says, it is full, although there are only about 6GB used on that device:

```
# df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        997M     0  997M   0% /dev
tmpfs                       202M   41M  162M  20% /run
/dev/mapper/p22server-root   73G   68G  655M 100% /
```

(I use LVM on the server: `/dev/mapper/p22server-root -> ../dm-0`)
If I check with

```
ncdu -x /
```

I find out that the total usage is just 5.9GB.

My guess is, that there must be files still open, that are not visible in the file-tree.

How can I debug this? I guess, that a reboot will restore the lost space, but rebooting is not possible right now.

Comment: Files [hidden behind a mount point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount)? I'm sure this question has come up before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

### 1. There are deleted files still open by some procesces

You can see all open files with `lsof`. For example those are the TYPEs shown in `lsof` and how often they appear in the output:

```
# lsof|cut -c50-54|sort|uniq -c
 375  CHR 
 610  DIR 
 211 FIFO 
  32 IPv4 
  17 IPv6 
  40 link 
 419 node 
 152 nown 
6008  REG 
   9 sock 
 598 unix
```

This shows only the File Descriptor column (FD):

```
# lsof|awk -v field="FD" 'NR==1 {c = index($0,field)} {print substr($0,c-1,length(field)+4)}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -n|tail
```

look for files with the value `DEL` in the output of `lsof` to get a hint.

---

### 2. Files are hidden behinid a mount point

But more probably, the files are just "hidden" due to a mount point, that was not used while large amount of files was stored in the mount-folder and now they are invisible to `ncdu`.

mount the root directory in another location and analyze this:

```
mkdir /temp-root
mount --bind / /temp-root
ncdu -x /temp_root
```

Answer (score 1):

If your suspicion is true, you may have an easier time with [lsof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof).

Look out for "(deleted)" or similar in the output.

Comment: I edited my question. there is no deleted entry in lsof