# Different mount points with df -Th and lsblk

Tags: disk-usage, lsblk

I am wondering why the output of `df -Th` and `lsblk` commands showing different mount points for logical volume `tmp`.

Server: RHEL v7.4

```
[root@mysystem ~]# df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-root         23G  7.6G   14G  37% /
devtmpfs                          16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                             16G   88K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             16G  217M   16G   2% /run
tmpfs                             16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                        488M  103M  350M  23% /boot
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-tmp         9.8G  107M  9.1G   2% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-var          20G 1000M   18G   6% /var
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-home        4.8G   27M  4.6G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-lv_var_log  7.8G   83M  7.3G   2% /var/log
```

And

```
[root@mysystem ~]# lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0   62G  0 disk
├─sda1                    8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                    8:2    0    4G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3                    8:3    0 57.5G  0 part
  ├─VOLGROUP-root       253:0    0 22.5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VOLGROUP-tmp        253:1    0   10G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
  ├─VOLGROUP-var        253:2    0   20G  0 lvm  /var
  └─VOLGROUP-home       253:3    0    5G  0 lvm  /home
sdb                       8:16   0    8G  0 disk
└─sdb1                    8:17   0    8G  0 part
  └─VOLGROUP-lv_var_log 253:4    0    8G  0 lvm  /var/log
sdc                       8:32   0  100G  0 disk
sr0                      11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Edited:

```
[root@mysystem ~]# cat /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=7d07bb2f-3b86-4481-ad72-bc4984cecfec /boot   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-home /home                   ext4    rw,suid,nodev,exec,nouser,async        1 2
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-tmp /tmp                     ext4    nodev,nosuid,noexec        1 2
/tmp   /var/tmp   none bind 0 0
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-var /var                     ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP-lv_var_log  /var/log         ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=bcb0f0ea-4443-4929-afcf-603c66776912 swap    swap    defaults        0 0
shmfs   /dev/shm        tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noexec     0 0
```

However for all other lv, mount points are same for both the commands. Or is there any difference in `Mounted on` and `MOUNTPOINT`?

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/fstab` as well?

Comment: @Haxiel Added.. I find `/tmp` bind `/var/tmp`. but couldn't get it.

Comment: That bind mount must be the cause for your observations. See this question for details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/173368