# Are bind mounts just another mount of the same filesystem?

Tags: mount, linux-kernel

I'm reading [What is a bind mount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount)

I tried `mount --bind -o ro / /mnt`, then I get the folowing two lines in `/proc/self/mountinfo`:

```bsh
23 0 0:21 /ARCHLINUX / rw,relatime shared:1 - btrfs /dev/sda rw,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/ARCHLINUX
268 23 0:21 /ARCHLINUX /mnt ro,relatime shared:1 - btrfs /dev/sda rw,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/ARCHLINUX
```

I can't see anything indicating it's a bind mount, it seems that kernel only treat the mount_id=268 as an individual mount of the device 0:21, it even supports different per-mount options(one is rw and another is ro)!

So is it true that a bind mount is exactly the same as mount the filesystem device twice? I'm using Linux 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the propagation mode is "private", if it is "shared" (default on systemd) then any child mount operations will be copied between the mount points.