# Unix: ".." doesn't point to parent -- how is this possible?

Tags: solaris, directory-structure, hard-link

I recently ran into the following problem on a Solaris 11 system
I do development on:

Somehow, a few directories had their parent pointer (`..`) pointing to
a different directory from the parent.

Let's call the parent directory `p`, and the directory in question
`d`  (i.e., `d` is in directory `p`.)

The situation was that `d/..` was not `p`.  Specifically, the two commands

```bsh
ls -ild  p

ls -ild  p/d/..
```

showed different i-node numbers.  In fact the second command gave
the same i-node as a different subdirectory of `p` : `p/x`

And, no `d` was not a symbolic link.  (That was the first thing I checked.)

How is this possible?  I would think the kernel would prevent it from ever
happening.

I do know that other people were moving directories around and renaming them,
though I don't know exactly what they did.  However, I don't think they would
know how to do systems hacking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a bind mount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount)

Comment: @ThomasDickey is that applicable to Solaris too?

Comment: yes - that's what I found quickly, and it's the simplest explanation.

Comment: You would need to give more information about filesystems and mountpoints.UFS e.g. supports hardlinked directories...

Comment: If you do `cd p/d/.. ; /bin/pwd` does it take you to p or x?

Comment: @ThomasDickey could you please give a link/reference for your quicky found bind mount support in Solaris? And also, how could I reproduce OP's case with bind mounts in Linux. I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Please show your exact commands and their output. Also mention what filesystem you're using (`df -g p p/d p/d/..`), and how you determined that `d` is not a symbolic link. Make sure `ls` is not an alias.

Comment: I looked for `solaris "bind mount"` and saw several promising ones such as [this](https://hosam.wordpress.com/tag/solaris-10/) and [this](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-suggestions-and-feedback/46498-exclude-bind-mounts-mount-bind-in-filesystem-discovery), i.e., a "loopback" mount.  What I supposed happened is that OP cd'd into a directory which was "really" under another directory, but bind-mounted into the directory where he began changing directories.  Whether you call it "bind" or "loopback" is just terminology (not interesting).

Comment: @ThomasDickey I'm not able to reproduce anything like the OP's case with either bind mounts in Linux or lofs in Solaris. Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a real answer to the original question and explain how to create this kind of state:

```
mkfile 100m ufs
lofiadm -a /path/to/ufs
newfs /dev/rlofi/1
newfs: Neues Dateisystem /dev/rlofi/1 erstellen: (y/n)? y
/dev/rlofi/1:   204600 Sektoren in 341 Zylindern von 1 Spuren, 600 Sektoren
        99,9MB in 22 Zylindergruppen (16 c/g, 4,69MB/g, 2240 i/g)
Superblock Backups (für fsck -F ufs -o b=#) bei:
 32, 9632, 19232, 28832, 38432, 48032, 57632, 67232, 76832, 86432,
 115232, 124832, 134432, 144032, 153632, 163232, 172832, 182432, 192032, 201632

mount /dev/lofi/1 /mnt
cd /mnt
mkdir -p a/b/c d

ls -lid a/b/ a/b/c a/b/c/..
     5 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         512 Apr 20 17:05 a/b/
     6 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         512 Apr 20 17:05 a/b/c
     5 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         512 Apr 20 17:05 a/b/c/..

link a/b/c/ d/hlink
ls -lid a/b/ a/b/c a/b/c/.. d/ d/hlink/ d/hlink/..
     5 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         512 Apr 20 17:05 a/b/
     6 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         512 Apr 20 17:05 a/b/c
     5 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         512 Apr 20 17:05 a/b/c/..
     7 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         512 Apr 20 17:08 d/
     6 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         512 Apr 20 17:05 d/hlink/
     5 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         512 Apr 20 17:05 d/hlink/..
```

This is creating a test [ufs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54777/ufs-7fs.html) filesystem in a file, which is then used as a block device via the [`lofi(7d)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36884/lofi-7d.html) "loopback file driver" (see `fbk` note below) and mounted on the `/mnt` directory. The ufs filesystem (unlike zfs) also supports creating hard links to directories, but only by root.

As you see, the inode number for `a/b/` is 5 and the inode number `of a/b/c/..` is 5 as well. You also see, that the link count for directory a/b/c increased by one from the `link` call.

After creating the new hardlinked directory `d/hlink`,  you see that the inode number for `d/hlink/..`is not 7 (the inode number of the directory above) but rather 5 (the inode number of the original directory above that directory).

BTW: the `loopback` filesystem first appeared in 1987 with SunOS-4.0. It's purpose is to act as a VFS indirect layer that allows to mount a filesystem tree a second time in the same machine. I am not sure whether this Linux bind mount is a reimplementation of the loopback filesystem idea.

What is obvious is that the [`fbk`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/kernel/fbk/) driver (file emulates block device) I invented in October 1988 has been reimplemented in the mid -1990s on linux under the improper name `loopback`.

Answer (score 0):

If we start from the premise that the simplest possibility is the most likely:

> *I do know that other people were moving directories around and renaming them, though I don't know exactly what they did.*

then the scenario should be relatively straightforward to reproduce. Consider this example run with prompts `1$` for the first terminal interspersed with `2$` for the second

```
# Set up the scenario
1$ mkdir a a/b a/b/c d
1$ cd a/b/c

# Look at the parent inode
1$ ls -lid ..
143279 drwxr-xr-x 3 roaima roaima 4096 Apr 20 08:42 ..

# Second session changes the directory structure
2$ mv a/b/c d

# Look at the parent inode once more - notice it's changed
1$ ls -lid ..
142603 drwxr-xr-x 3 roaima roaima 4096 Apr 20 08:43
```