# Failed to restart nfs-server.service: Transaction order is cyclic

Tags: nfs

NFS has been working for more than a year with the current configuration but has recently developed this issue:

Ubuntu 20.04
Kernel 5.40.0-40
NFS  nfs-kernel-server/focal-updates,focal-security,now 1:1.3.4-2.5ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed]

```
systemctl restart nfs-server

Failed to restart nfs-server.service: Transaction order is cyclic. See system logs for details.
See system logs and 'systemctl status nfs-server.service' for details.
```

systemctl status :

```
 systemctl status nfs-server
 nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
         └─order-with-mounts.conf
 Active: inactive (dead)

 Jul 03 06:37:38 acer systemd[1]: export-3T.mount: Found ordering cycle on nfs-server.service/start
 Jul 03 06:37:38 acer systemd[1]: export-3T.mount: Found dependency on export-3T.mount/start
 Jul 03 06:37:38 acer systemd[1]: export-3T.mount: Unable to break cycle starting with export-3T.mount/start
 Jul 03 06:43:47 acer systemd[1]: export-3T.mount: Found ordering cycle on nfs-server.service/start
 Jul 03 06:43:47 acer systemd[1]: export-3T.mount: Found dependency on export-3T.mount/start
 Jul 03 06:43:47 acer systemd[1]: export-3T.mount: Unable to break cycle starting with export-3T.mount/start
```

From journal

```
systemd[1]: Requested transaction contains an unfixable cyclic ordering dependency: Transaction order is cyclic. See system logs for det>
systemd[1]: export-3T.mount: Unable to break cycle starting with export-3T.mount/start
systemd[1]: export-3T.mount: Found dependency on export-3T.mount/start
systemd[1]: export-3T.mount: Found ordering cycle on nfs-server.service/start
```

/etc/fstab

```
UUID=uid /mnt/3T ext4 defaults 0 0 
/mnt/3T /export/3T nfs bind 0 0
```

/etc/exports

```
/export/3T 10.0.0.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

Comment: @Archemar added `fstab` and `exports` entries.

Comment: @Archemar Sorry. I don't follow. How am I hiding `3T` under a remote dir? `/export/3T` is local to the same host that is mounting `3T` to `/mnt`. I nfs-export from the `/export/` directory. I don't understand how that makes `/export` a remote directory? I don't doubt you, but please explain.

Comment: I was puzzled by `nfs bind` in `fstab`. may be you want to look at Gille's  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount

Comment: @Archemar That is to hide the server's file structure from NFS clients. I understand that to be fairly standard procedure. See `bind` in this article https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS   I don't see how this gets us closer to the issue I'm having.

Comment: Maybe the export process from NFS server is run before your bind mount. Did you try to : comment the export line in exports file, reboot (nfs server  should start normally), then uncomment the line and restart the NFS server again.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

I was recently affected by this issue again, and the below didn't resolve the issue. I did find a "correct"(?) fix that has been stable for us.

The solution is to not put your mount in `/etc/fstab`. Rather, create a `systemd` **mount** unit for your mount point. Useful links include:

- https://dev.to/adarshkkumar/mount-a-volume-using-systemd-1h2f
- https://tekneed.com/how-to-mount-volumes-using-systemd-unit-file/
- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/root-tip-systemd-mount-unit-samples/1191

In your case, you'd want `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-3T.mount` that looks something like this (untested):

```
[Unit]
Description=3T mount
After=network.target

[Mount]
Where=/mnt/3T
Type=nfs
Options=bind

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(I've never done an NFS bind mount before; you may need to tweak `Requires=` and `After=` to achieve the order you want)

### Original Answer

This is a bit old, but I see various flavors of this issue reported in several places. For me, the key was https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183999 or more specifically, adding `DefaultDependencies=False` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-client.target`

The error message is surprisingly clear, but not necessarily intuitive. `systemd` has a cycle in the dependencies between units. The question is how to break that cycle. [This blog](https://trstringer.com/systemd-defaultdependencies-ordering-cycle/) describes the issue in more detail.

Also, the systemd unit manual pages describe default dependencies. For example, the *target*.target man page includes this:

> ### Default Dependencies
>
> The following dependencies are added unless `DefaultDependencies=no` is set:
>
> - Target units will automatically complement all configured dependencies of type `Wants=` or `Requires=` with dependencies of type `After=` unless `DefaultDependencies=no` is set in the specified units. Note that `Wants=` or `Requires=` must be defined in the target unit itself — if you for example define `Wants=`some.target in some.service, the automatic ordering will not be added.

In the case of NFS, I can't say explicitly what causes the cycle between the NFS server and the NFS client, but I can say empirically that when I disabled `DefaultDependencies` in the `nfs-client.target`, my problem went away. Cycle broken.