# Prevent a symlink to root directory from being unmounted

Tags: linux, symlink, nfs

I have a symlink etablished under `/mnt/` like so `ln -s / /mnt/$(HOSTNAME)`. This is so that I can easily access multiple nfs mounted disks, including the host machine itself. But recently a colleague noticed that this has the risk of unmounting the host root directory itself, which makes it impossible to login. So is there any trick/tactic to prevent unmounting the target of a symlink?

Comment: Does it have to be a symlink? Could a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198591/244846) work for your use-case?

Comment: @Thegs that works too! Thanks for the suggestion and I will look into that.