# hide files matching pattern in bindfs mount

Tags: mount, fuse

I want to mount a copy of a directory in such a way that files/subdirectories matching a pattern are hidden. When mounting with write permission that could obviously cause problems in case a hidden file was created a second time, but when mounting read-only it should be OK?

Is something like that possible with `bindfs`? Or is there an alternative way to achieve something comparable?

Comment: Bindfs doesn't have this feature. Maybe try looking at some of the filesystems listed at the end of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount/198591#198591), though beware that it's a few years old and some filesystems I list might not be maintained anymore. For example, that's filterfs's main feature, but it doesn't seem to have been updated since 2012 so I can't recommend it today.

Comment: ahh thanks! I was looking at this answer but didn't scroll down far enough!

Comment: unfurtunately -- as you say -- filterfs is not maintained and I can't even clone the git. EDIT: this one might work: https://github.com/gjvnq/filterfs