# Accessing directories outside of chroot jail

Tags: sftp, chroot

I'm setting up an SFTP server that several different clients will use.

My main issue is that it's absolutely crucial that employees of one client *DO NOT* see even the directory names of other clients' directories.

Right now user `janedoe` gets chroot access to `/sftp/janedoe/home`. They cannot access outside directories.

I need `janedoe` to be able to access `/sftp/projects/Walmart-ProjectABC` and I *cannot* have `janedoe` see directory `/sftp/projects/Kmart-ProjectXYZ`. `janedoe` will have several colleagues that need to access the same directory, so I cannot just stick that project directory in their home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Use [bind mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) to construct what each user can see.

For example (under Linux), chroot janedoe to `/sftp/janedoe` and give her access to the `Walmart-ProjectABC` project:

```
mkdir /sftp/janedoe/Walmart-ProjectABC
mount --bind /sftp/projects/Walmart-ProjectABC /sftp/janedoe/Walmart-ProjectABC
```

This can be a line in `/etc/fstab` if you want to make all of these static, or a script that runs before switching to the user if you want to make them dynamic.

The directory that is the mount point (`/sftp/janedoe/Walmart-ProjectABC`) should not be modifiable or movable by the user, to avoid having to handle errors in case the user moves it or somehow creates files in it.